# Why 'cp --preserve=links' doesn't work?

Tags: cp

Why `cp --preserve=links` doesn't work?
I want to copy some symbolic links.From man page:

> `--preserve[=ATTR_LIST]`
>   preserve the specified attributes (default: mode,ownership,timestamps),
>   if possible additional attributes: context, links, xattr, all*

On my CentOS 3.10.0-693.el7.x86_64,it doesn't work.

Following is my steps:

```
[root@ beau]# ls -l
total 4
lrwxrwxrwx. 1 root root 11 Dec 2 21:49 bar.txt -> foo/bar.txt
drwxr-xr-x. 2 root root 4096 Dec 2 21:41 foo
[root@ beau]# cp --preserve=links bar.txt bar1
[root@ beau]# ls -l
total 4
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root 0 Dec 2 23:08 bar1
lrwxrwxrwx. 1 root root 11 Dec 2 21:49 bar.txt -> foo/bar.txt
drwxr-xr-x. 2 root root 4096 Dec 2 21:41 foo
```

My questions is :Why the option '--preserve=links' doesn't work?

Comment: Where did that text at the top come from? Was it copied from another question or site?

Answer (score 1):

In brief: `--preserve=links` refers to preserving *hard links*, not symlinks. `-P` or `--no-dereference` preserves symbolic links by copying the links themselves, not their targets. `-P` is standard, in GNU cp it's included in `-d`, which is included in `-a`.